# Does constant pressure cause muscle atrophy, and if so, why?

Tags: muscles

I read on https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Gluteal_muscles&oldid=876760828#Clinical_significance:

> Sitting for long periods can lead to the gluteal muscles atrophying through constant pressure and disuse.

However, the statement isn't supported by any reference. Does constant pressure cause muscle atrophy, and if so, why?

---

I tried to find some references stating that constant pressure causes muscle atrophy, but I haven't found any so far. The following information sources don't list constant pressure as a cause of on muscle atrophy:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Muscle_atrophy&oldid=884590568
- https://vet.uga.edu/ivcvm/courses/VPAT5200/02_injury/atrophy/atrophy01b.htm  ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/2/https://vet.uga.edu/ivcvm/courses/VPAT5200/02_injury/atrophy/atrophy01b.htm))

Comment: I think it's likely you found a scientifically unfounded and (if we want to be very pendantic) inaccurate sentence on Wikipedia. It's unsourced, and colloquially stated. Disuse causes atrophy, and pressure is simply something that doesn't help. Pressure probably does not lead to atrophy; hearts don't atrophy simply due to being exposed to ever-present pressure from circulating blood. The pressure might even slow down atrophy in such cases. One could make a case for sitting restricting blood flow to the muscle, which could be a mild contributor in the long run.

Comment: @S Pr: But bedsores are caused by constant pressure on areas of the body, including people in wheelchairs: https://www.hopkinsmedicine.org/health/conditions-and-diseases/bedsores  Though I doubt that normal sitting would be sufficient.